# Teradata / A list as an input for procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, teradata

I would like to create an procedure, which receives an list as an input and uses it in `WHERE` clause. How to do that?
The code might look like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE proc (list VARCHAR(300 /*which format should i use???*/))
BEGIN
CREATE MULTISET TABLE t1 AS
(
SELECT *
FROM parent_table
WHERE opt IN list
)
WITH DATA;
END;

CALL proc (31,22,11,44,65,51);
```

Thx!

Comment: Send the input as comma separated string. In where clause split the csv to individual rows and filter it using `IN`

Comment: could you plese provide code for example ?

Comment: This question has been asked previously on SO. In the search box put the following `[teradata] dynamic sql`. One of the first questions has an example of providing IN list conditionals to a procedure.